# Correlate/pivot boolean columns

Tags: sql, ms-access, pivot

I have a table `attendance` that lists meeting dates and attendance by representatives of 4 quadrants:

```
Date     N S E W
1/1/2021 T T T T
1/3/2021 F T T T
1/4/2021 F F T T
```

etc.

What I want is to find the last date the various representatives were in the same room as each other:

```
  N          S            E                W
N 1/1/2021   1/1/2021     1/1/2021        1/1/2021
S 1/1/2021   1/3/2021     1/3/2021        1/3/2021
E 1/1/2021   1/3/2021     1/3/2021        1/4/2021
W 1/1/2021   1/3/2021     1/4/2021        1/4/2021
```

I've been trying to use TRANSFORM/cross-tab, but I think I need to PIVOT longer before I can do that, and PIVOT doesn't seem possible in Access.

I'd love to hear suggestions or approaches to this.

Comment: what should the ones with two of the same be -- the last date that was T?

Comment: Yes - the most recent date

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hmmm . . . you can unpivot and reaggregate.  This is painful in MS Access, but you can use:

```
select t1.which,
       max(iif(t2.which = 'N' then date end) as N,
       max(iif(t2.which = 'S' then date end) as S,
       max(iif(t2.which = 'E' then date end) as E,
       max(iif(t2.which = 'W' then date end) as W
from (select date, 'N' as which from t where N = 'T' union all
      select date, 'S' from t where S = 'T' union all
      select date, 'E' from t where E = 'T' union all
      select date, 'W' from t where W = 'T'
     ) as t1 inner join
     (select date, 'N' as which from t where N = 'T' union all
      select date, 'S' from t where S = 'T' union all
      select date, 'E' from t where E = 'T' union all
      select date, 'W' from t where W = 'T'
     ) as t2
     on t1.date = t2.date
group by t1.which;
```

An alternative method isn't that bad for 4 people but it doesn't scale well:

```
select which, max(N) as n, max(S) as s, max(E) as e, max(W) as w
from (select N as which,
             date as N,
             iif(S = 'T', date, null) as S,
             iif(E = 'T', date, null) as E,
             iif(W = 'T', date, null) as W
      from t
      union all
      select S,
             iif(N = 'T', date, null) as N,
             date as S,
             iif(E = 'T', date, null) as E,
             iif(W = 'T', date, null) as W
      from t
      union all
      select S,
             iif(N = 'T', date, null) as N,
             iif(S = 'T', date, null) as S,
             date as E,
             iif(W = 'T', date, null) as W
      from t
      union all
      select S,
             iif(N = 'T', date, null) as N,
             iif(S = 'T', date, null) as S,
             iif(E = 'T', date, null) as E,
             date as W,
      from t
     ) as tt
group by which;
```

Comment: I feel like there is a way to do this with ROW_NUMBER()....

Comment: @Hogan . . . definitely not in MS Access.

Comment: I ended up using the first option, but using select * from... and then doing a second crosstab query on that using max().  I think the iif syntax was a bit off, but this fit my brain better and allowed me to do an additional query of "number of times together" using the same base query.   Thank you @GordonLinoff!